# How to make type annotated mouse over html files with HsColour

Tags: haskell

The 
[HsColour](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hscolour) package is capable over producing html with mouse over type annotations, an [example can be found on the site of the creator of the feature](http://goto.ucsd.edu/~rjhala/Annot/hscolour/src/Language-Haskell-HsColour-CSS.html#hscolour).

How do I use hscolour to produce html with annotated mouse overs? Do I need another program to produce the annotations and if so what is it?

Comment: Your first link is broken. The link should use all lowercase `hscolour`.

Comment: @ScottOlson thanks I was going off the name of the executable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate the type annotations using Haddock, with the `--annot=FILE` flag, where `FILE` is the filename of the file you want to generate. You can then pass the same argument (`--annot=FILE`) to HsColour.

Comment: Did the --annot=FILE flag actually get added to haddock? My recollection was that my patch couldn't be accepted because of a dependency on syb, and then I never found the time to extricate that dependency...

Comment: @RanjitJhala I can not see to find the repo in your github account or a branch on the main haddock git. Is there a repository or a tarball that I can grab somewhere with the annotation functionality?

Comment: @Davorak ah sorry about that. Here you go: https://github.com/ranjitjhala/haddock-annot You needn't rebuild the cabal packages if you want to do this for a single file of course...